# openssl_seal problems

Tags: php, openssl

I'm having some problems loading in a public key for encrypting using openssl_seal function in PHP...

I've created the public & private keys using the openSSL command line tool:

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out private.pem 1024

openssl rsa -in private.pem -out public.pem -outform PEM -pubout
```

However, when I run it in my PHP code I get the following errors:

```
openssl_seal() [function.openssl-seal]: Don't know how to get public key from this private key
openssl_seal() [function.openssl-seal]: not a public key (1th member of pubkeys)
```

When I verify the public key using: openssl verify public.pem, I get:

```
unable to load certificate
1876:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:.\crypto\pem\pem_lib
.c:648:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE
```

Anyone know why this is happening?

PHP Code:

```
public function encrypt($valueToEncrypt, $publicKeyFile)
{
    $pk = file_get_contents($publicKeyFile);
    $publicKey = openssl_pkey_get_public($pk);

    $encrypted = '';
    $a_envelope = array();
    $a_key = array($publicKey);
    if (openssl_seal($valueToEncrypt, $encrypted, $a_envelope, $a_key) === FALSE)
            {
                while ($msg = openssl_error_string())
                    echo $msg . "<br />\n";
                die('Failed to encrypt data!');
            }
            openssl_free_key($publicKey);
....
```

Comment: Please add your PHP code. Kinda hard to see what's wrong without it. From the looks of the message though I'd assume you're passing a private key where you should be passing a public key.

Comment: Code added... checked file and it's the public key.
Also get this: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line on loading public key

Answer (score 1):

For anyone experiencing the same problem, the issue related to an install of xampp on windows. Running on the command line on a fresh install of just php worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to  StuffandBlah's answer: It is in fact related to the different OpenSSL versions in Apache and PHP in XAMPP on Windows. Here's [a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11399613/issues-with-openssl-on-php-different-behaviour-for-different-versions/11427989#11427989) of how to solve the problem (copying DLLs).