# Issues with OpenSSL on PHP - different behaviour for different versions

Tags: php, openssl, public-key-encryption

*(This question was originally posted on ServerFault - I have deleted it there and moved it here.)*

I have a development machine running PHP 5.3.5 and a production machine running PHP 5.3.8.

The following code runs on the development machine:

```
<?php
$key = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQC0x+2RiQ+LCZNAUcl/Ecf1NrTr
lhjOiHaVC+w/y+UJevqVcDstD22OJGwT13B9T47OuQG9BmzcZQYLcShUMhVD/Owu
9+8PcK51EnBd0lym6+z/WixpnqfQonyKiqq5ytmYKUlUv39J8QQUI2geyvY9VpWS
wyNcFUs7wPl2zsLCPQIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";

$data = "Hello, world!";

$key1 = openssl_get_publickey($key);
print_r ($key1);
echo "<p>";

$res = openssl_public_encrypt($data, $encrypted_data, $key1, OPENSSL_PKCS1_PADDING);

echo base64_encode($encrypted_data);
```

On my development machine, this code outputs a resource and an encoded string. I would copy it here, but of course it changes each time. On the production machine, this code produces the resource number and the following PHP errors:

```
PHP Warning:  openssl_public_encrypt(): Don't know how to get public key from this private key in C:\xxx\test.php on line 15
PHP Warning:  openssl_public_encrypt(): key parameter is not a valid public key in C:\xxx\test.php on line 15
```

Unfortunately, installing an older version of PHP on the production machine is not an option at the moment because of other applications that are running on it which require 5.3.8 as a minimum.

Would it help if I upgraded to 5.4.x?

I do know that the version of OpenSSL on 5.3.5 is 0.9.8 whereas the version in 5.3.8 is 1.0.0. I imagine that there might be a problem there. Is there any way to work around that?

I have tried to find out as much as I can from the OpenSSL.org site, and the PHP bug tracker, but I don't know what I'm looking for.

Regards,

Philip

Comment: Have you compared the settings of each php.ini configuration file?

Comment: @RobB: Superficially, yes. Both have the OpenSSL extension loaded. Neither file has any further OpenSSL settings. What else should I look for?

Comment: @RobB I've done a diff on the two php.ini files - there are no significant differences between the two that can't be explained by the fact that one is a production server and one is a development server.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10422268/openssl-seal-problems), the issue is related to different OpenSSL versions of Apache and PHP in the XAMPP/Windows installation. I had a similar issue with openssl_verify. I solved it by using the same OpenSSL version for both Apache and PHP (replacing DLLs). Here's a [link to the solution](http://www.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?p=190619#p194972).

*"I found a solution for the problem, it seems there are 2 wrong files in /apache/bin/ in the default 1.7.7 installation that need to be replaced by the files existing in /php/ (libeay32.ddl and ssleay32.dll)"*

Comment: Thanks. I can confirm that I replaced libeay32.dll and openssl.exe. From there, it seemed to work. Perhaps only the libeay32.dll needs to change?

Answer (score 0):

You passed the wrong parameter of `openssl_public_encrypt`

`openssl_public_encrypt($data, $encrypted_data, $key1, OPENSSL_PKCS1_PADDING)`

where `$key1` is the resource id use `$key` instead of `$key1`. You can use

`openssl_public_encrypt($data, $encrypted_data, $key, OPENSSL_PKCS1_PADDING)`