# openssl_verify(): Don't know how to get public key from this private key on production server

Tags: laravel

I developed an API with Laravel which runs perfectly on localhost/endpoint but as soon as I uploaded on the server. I received an error on **openssl_verify(): Don't know how to get public key from this private key**

Please, what could be wrong? I read it could be PHP settings on the production server. What do I need to do to it

[image]

**This is the image of the one on the local Server**

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Issues with OpenSSL on PHP - different behaviour for different versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11399613/issues-with-openssl-on-php-different-behaviour-for-different-versions)

Comment: Thanks he is talking about .dll, I am on Mac

Comment: I don't think it matters. Try to use the same version of openssl on both systems.